# Read from bottom to top in PHP & SQL

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a chat wich uses Databases. When i display the message the old messages come on top and the new messages come on the bottom. How can i make it so the new messages come on top. I have already tried the `ORDER BY Username DESC` but that only made it go in alphabetical order.

This is my full code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jetup</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="chatform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="chatuser"/>
<input type="text" name="chatinput"/>
<input type="image" name="send" value="Verzenden"/>
<br/>
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","usbw") or die ("Kon geen verbinding maken");
    mysql_select_db("chat") or die("Kan geen database selecteren");

    if(isset($_POST['chatinput']) && isset($_POST['chatuser'])){
        $input = $_POST['chatinput'];
        $user = $_POST['chatuser'];


        $query = "INSERT INTO chatterdata (Username, Message) VALUES ('".$user."', '" .$input."')";
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    $display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chatterdata ORDER BY Username DESC, Message DESC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($display)){
        echo($row['Username'] . " : " .$row['Message'] . "<br/>");
    }
?>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: order by datetime of message. `INSERT INTO chatterdata (Username, Message, created_at) VALUES (... NOW())`

Comment: Instead of ordering by the username, order by the date. Or you could order by the date, then order by the username. `ORDER BY Date DESC, Username DESC`

Comment: I searched random solutions on Google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a timestamp field to your chatterdata table.

then you can order by this field

```
`added` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

This is an example field which will be automatically updated when you add a new message, so you don't need to insert anything else to the database when creating a message.

then you can select like this:

```
SELECT * FROM chatterdata ORDER BY added DESC
```

I would definitely look at using PDO, or at very least mysql_real_escape_string before inserting valuues to the database, as there's huge security implications in doing this :-)

Comment: Thanks alot, worked for me! :D Cant +1 you though, just lost my reputation xD

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work by creating a `SentDate` field, and ordering by the `SentDate` field.

```
INSERT INTO chatterdata(Username, Message, SentDate) VALUES ($user, $message, NOW())
```

Since a newer date and time will be greater than a previous message, the newer one will appear on top.

Comment: Thanks alot fot the answer!!