# Ordering the result from last to first?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm really looking for help, and [Read from bottom to top in PHP & SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218265/read-from-bottom-to-top-in-php-sql) doesn't quite help me; I do not do MySQL.

What I'm basically trying to do is to read a database table from bottom to top. Unlike the fact that it currently reads from top to bottom, I would like it from the bottom. Is there a PHP function or code that instead starts reading from bottom?

Here is the code that reads the database:

```
 <?php
//Here is the connecting to database stuff; works fine and not going to share it

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM posts");
//This has PHP select and read the table (at least I think it does; I'm not the best coder in the world)


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<h4>";  
  echo $row['username'];
  echo "</h4><p>";
  echo $row['message'];
  echo "</p>";
  }
//All this stuff just reads and echos the data
mysqli_close($con);
//Closes database connection
?>
```

Comment: What columns/type you have on posts table? Post your structure.

Comment: Are you asking about `order`ing of returned records?

Comment: Why cant you use `ORDER BY` in your query? it is much simpler. I also don't recommend `SELECT * ...` `*` is too confusing for field names to maintain

Comment: In case this would help, since you guys seem to want it, the structure of the table is username and message. Shouldn't this be a much easier function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query should be like this:
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY field DESC

Comment: Thank you for this tip! It worked. :D (can't vote up yet;  but I would if I could)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "ORDER BY":

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY field DESC");
```

The "field" in this case will probably be "id", as I am assuming you are using it as a  primary key in your posts table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY DESC` to arrange the resultset in descending order

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY postid DESC;
```

replace `postid` with primary key of `posts` table

Comment: Why are you using two ORDER BY? Refer to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify a field on which sorting has to be performed, you can't fetch results in the desired order but the default.

If you want to sort fields by, say post_id, then, you can use like:

```
select * from posts order by post_id desc
```

And if you still want to fetch records in their default positions but want to display from last to first order, then you need a temp row number variable while selecting and then to re-order the display records.

***Example***:

```
select 
  @rn:=@rn+1 as row_num, 
  posts.*
from 
  posts,
  ( select @rn:=0 ) tmp_row_nums order by post_id desc
```